# Adding rectangles to an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, libgdx

I'm trying to add more than one rectangle into an ArrayList ("rectPlatform") using the `addAll` for it.
The rectangles I want to add to my ArrayList are:

```
Rectangle rectOne;
Rectangle rectTwo;
Rectangle rectThree;
```

I tried a lot, but I didn't get any success trying to `addAll` rectangles into the `rectPlatform`.
Can anybody help me please to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddAll` only works for collections, normally the `List`, `Queue` and `Set` interface implementing classes. So to make your code work, your `Rectangle` objects would have to already be in a collection.

You could also try:

```
List<Rectangle> rectList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Rectangle[]{rectOne, rectTwo, rectThree}));
```

Or another way:

```
List<Rectangle> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(rectOne);
list1.add(rectTwo);
list1.add(rectThree);
List<Rectangle> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```